# Can having an incorrect hair color on my FAA medical certificate get me in trouble?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

I just got a new FAA medical certificate, and I accidentally put down that my hair color is blonde when in reality it is dark brown. Also, my hair is listed as brown on my pilot certificate.

I bleach my hair in the summer, which makes it blonde.

Would such a small detail cause any sort of trouble?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This probably won't cause you any practical trouble unless you go for a new certificate or rating (the data on your medical needs to match the data on your IACRA form which needs to match your existing certificates - an examiner may refuse to conduct a test if there are discrepancies).

It's something you should correct though: It's presumed your hair color on the medical is your *natural* hair color, and if you get ramp checked you don't want to have to explain the discrepancy.

---

Counterintuitively the answer for "How do I fix this?" is buried [in the IACRA FAQ](https://iacra.faa.gov/iacra/faq.aspx):

> **Q:**    The data on my medical certificate does not match what is in the FAA Airman Registry database, what should I do?
>
> **A:**    If it is less than 60 days since the date of issue of your certificate, contact your AME (Aeromedical Examiner) for resolution of this issue. If it is 60 days or more since the date of issue of your certificate, contact the FAA Aerospace Medical Certification Division for resolution of this issue. The contact info is below.
>
> ```
> Aerospace Medical Certification Division, AAM-300 
> Federal Aviation Administration Civil Aerospace Medical Institute 
> P.O. Box 25082 Oklahoma City, OK 73125
> Tel: (405) 954-4821
> ```

Comment: Thanks.  My address is also different from my pilot cert (my pilot cert is my home address, and my medical is my school).  So I will contact my medical examiner to get both of those things changed.

Comment: got to wonder how they deal with aging pilots. Hair tends to change colour over time, adding grey and eventually going white (or disappearing completely) :)

Comment: @jwenting Well there's always hair dye and toupees :-) Seriously though: in that case your pilot certificate would become inaccurate, and [there's a procedure to fix that too](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/9150/64). (This is The Government - there's a form or procedure for EVERYTHING!)

Comment: and no doubt a fee :) Many government requirements seem designed to make you spend money on other government programs in order to meet said requirements and no other reason.

Comment: Why does the FAA even care about your hair color?