# How do you correct a mistake on a pilot license?

Tags: faa-regulations

If a mistake is found on a pilot license, like the pilot's nationality, date of birth, or a missing type rating, how would one go about having it corrected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this happen to me on my first license. I got in touch with the FAA Examiner and he had me contact the local Flight Standards Office (FSDO) who corrected it for me.

---

If it was a mistake on the application, your Certifying Officer (read: FAA Examainer) can allow you to edit the information through IACRA (https://iacra.faa.gov/iacra/default.aspx) and the license re-issued.

If all of the information was correct, but it was misprinted, you would want to call your local FSDO.

FSDO Search: http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/

Your local FSDO can help you with:

- Low-flying aircraft
- Accident Reporting
- Air carrier certification and operations
- Aircraft maintenance
- Aircraft operational issues
- Aircraft permits
- **Airmen certification (licensing) for pilots, mechanics, repairmen, dispatchers, and parachute riggers**
- **Certification and modification issues**
- Enforcement of Airmen & Aircraft Regulations

Answer (score 3):

Contact [your FSDO](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/field_offices/fsdo/).

Changing personal details like date of birth or nationality requires the pilot to [visit the FSDO personally](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/lic_cert/change/name_change/).

It's hard to see how a type rating could be missing because completion of the rating should be logged in [IACRA](https://iacra.faa.gov/iacra/) and that will trigger the issuance of a new license, so the 'worst' that could happen is that the FAA doesn't issue the new certificate quickly enough.

But obviously sometimes things just go wrong (I had an instrument rating go missing completely, despite IACRA) and in that case you would also follow up with the FSDO to get the certificate re-issued or corrected.