# What should I do to resolve an incorrect birth date on my FAA medical certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical, student-pilot

While taking my pre-solo exam, I noticed my medical has my birth date one year earlier than it actually is. I am expecting to solo tomorrow.

Would this error legally prohibit me from soloing until it is corrected?

Comment: Are you old enough to solo without the "extra" year of age?  Did you put the correct year in when you filled out the FAA MedXpress form?

Comment: Yes, I am old enough. I got my medical before the changes recently so my AME filled out the forms then. He must have put it in wrong by accident.

Comment: Related: [How do you correct a mistake on a pilot license?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9135/how-do-you-correct-a-mistake-on-a-pilot-license/9150#9150)

Comment: Related: [Wrong hair color on my medical?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9117/wrong-hair-color-on-my-medical)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read the FARs for this one, and there is a rule:

**[14 CFR §67.403 Applications, certificates, logbooks, reports, and records: Falsification, reproduction, or alteration; incorrect statements.](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=912310b5802d43b7d1e6291bfc7340e2&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.1.5.5.1.2&idno=14)**

From what I gather, the rule is there to get liars in trouble.

If you didn't lie, which you clearly have no reason to because your age does not disqualify you, I don't think you have to worry about getting in trouble because it was the doctor's mistake.

However: ([From 67.403](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=912310b5802d43b7d1e6291bfc7340e2&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.1.5.5.1.2&idno=14))

> (c) The following may serve as a basis for suspending or revoking a
> medical certificate; withdrawing an Authorization or SODA; or denying
> an application for a medical certificate or request for an
> authorization or SODA:
>
> (2) **An incorrect entry**, upon which the FAA relied, **made in any
> logbook, record, or report that is kept, made, or used to show
> compliance with any requirement for a medical certificate** or an
> Authorization or SODA. [My emphasis]

Let's pull out the important words and we get this:

"An incorrect entry ... made in any ... record, or report that is **kept ... or used** to show compliance with any requirement for a medical certificate..."

A medical certificate is certainly **kept or used to show compliance** with a [requirement to posses a medical certificate **§61.3(c)(1)**](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=daa7831942ba4a74cd7aa2560eeafb51&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_13&rgn=div8)

You have discovered an incorrect entry.  Call the doctor that issued your medical as soon as you can in order to get it resolved, and do not accept a solo sign-off on this incorrectly filed document now that you have knowledge of the mistake.

To give you a straight answer based on my interpretation of the law, **yes; this error would prohibit you from soloing until it can be corrected.**